# Neomutt Uses the Wrong Shell Even After Setting the Shell Variable

Tags: bash, shell, configuration, email, mutt

None of my aliases are working in neomutt. This prevents me from editing files in my text editor neovim. If I try I get an error `sh: 1: nvim not fount` indicating that the shell being used here is `sh` . I use bash on my system so I looked for a way to change this. I added `set shell = "/bin/bash"` to my config but this has not changed matters, the shell in neomutt is still sh

Comment: Even if mutt were using bash, aliases don't work by default in non-interactive shells. You better create a executable scriptlet than an alias for whatever you're using as the editor.

Comment: Please paste the real error message (we get so many unsolvable questions, because people don't paste what really happened).

Comment: That's the real error message

Answer (score 0):

As @user414777 pointed out, aliases don't work in non interactive shells. What fixed this for me was changing my `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR` environment variables to `nvim.appimage`. In my case, because I didn't install neovim through my distribution's package manager and instead installed it as an appimage executable, the neovim command was only an alias to that executable. If you are having the same problem but have installed neovim through other means (i.e. by not downloading an appimage file) then you should first find the location of the executable and either created a script that points to it or make the same changes that I did.